# Where do the imported containerd images get stored on a linux machine

Tags: docker, containers, k3s, containerd

I have k3s installed on a machine
when I do a
ctr image pull docker.io/calico/node:v3.11.2 or a ctr image import  , where do the images get stored on the file system?
I am assuming some location on /var/lib/rancher or /run/k3s/contianerd , but not able to figure out the exact location

I am looking for the exact file path where the images get stored

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.